# What filter to use in SQL Profiler for socket write error

Tags: sql-server, profiler

Can someone please help with intitial SQL Profiler filter setup to narrow down the settings and reduce the noise when I'm trying to find out the reason behind socket write error ?

Basically the problem is that certain integration software is dropping xml files along the way from one application to the end application but some go through. There are the errors in the log. After we restarted the sql and app server first two days no messages were dropped.

I need to figure out the possible reason. We will probably have to run the profiler for 24 hours because the error appear only occasionaly so if there is too much data it becomes useless. Any help appreaciated. Thank you.

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ASSET-DB-02;instance=test;DatabaseName=MonitorEngine'
I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Comment: What is the exact version of SQL Server?  Can you provide any relevant details from the SQL Server Error Log?

Comment: I am not aware of SQL Profiler being able to capture socket errors. Might check this post out, references a particular message found in SQL Server ERRORLOG: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/16f8ef7f-9488-46c6-a750-e767db22fd7e/connection-reset-by-peersql-server-2008?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Network issues have additional details [logged to a ring buffer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16587/3690) dependant on version.

Comment: I think you need to narrow the focus to either the SQL side or the app side. Restarting both of them at once didn't give any feedback about the problem. It's possible the problem is related to the network itself, too.